# See if contents in one list partially matches contents in another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to see if the contents of column B matches the contents of column A.

**Column A** 

SULFAMETHOXAZOLE-TMP DS TABLET 500 EACH x 1 

BENAZEPRIL HCL 20 MG TABLET 500 EACH x 1

AMLODIPINE BESYLATE 5 MG TAB 90 EACH x 1

ANDRODERM 4 MG/24HR PATCH 30 EACH x 1

ACYCLOVIR 800 MG TABLET 500 EACH x 1

SIMVASTATIN 10 MG TABLET 90 EACH x 1

TAMSULOSIN HCL 0.4 MG CAPSULE 100 EACH x 1

SIMVASTATIN 20 MG TABLET 90 EACH x 1

**Column B**

Lovastatin

Amlodipine

Glargine

Pitavastatin

Doxazosin

Tamulosin

Clindamycin

Coumadin

How do I specify a partial match?

Additionally, my data contents are huge so I need to run the match from A1:A1000 with B1:B1000, etc.

I've tried VLOOKUP, IFs formulas.

Comment: something like this: `=COUNTIF(A:A, "*" & B1 & "*")>0` or `=ISNUMBER(MATCH("*" & B1 & "*", A:A, 0))`?

Comment: Kindly mark  my answer as correct if it helps:) See this link for details: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 1):

As follow up from comments, next formulas works:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH("*" & B1 & "*", A:A, 0))
```

or

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, "*" & B1 & "*")>0
```

both returns `True`/`False`